# automatic GWT ClientBundles based on disk files

Tags: gwt, clientbundle

I'm currently making good use of GWT's [ClientBundles](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) in my app. It works fine, but I have a large number of resources and it becomes tedious to manually create Java interfaces for each file:

```
@ClientBundle.Source("world_war_ii.txt")
public ExternalTextResource worldWarII();

@ClientBundle.Source("spain.txt")
public ExternalTextResource spain();

@ClientBundle.Source("france.txt")
public ExternalTextResource france();
```

I'd like to be able to (perhaps at compile time) dynamically list every *.txt file in a given directory, and then have run-time access to them, perhaps as an array `ExternalTextResource[]`, rather than having to explicitly list them in my code. There may be hundreds of such resources, and enumerating them manually as code would be very painful and unmaintainable.

The `ClientBundle` documentation explicitly says that "to provide a file-system abstraction"  is a non-goal, so unfortunately this seems to disallow what I'm trying to do.

**What's the best way to deal with a large number of external resources that must be available at run-time?** Would a generator help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following [this advice](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/bb7a83d35a038107/ed9a23e4544a5aa8?lnk=gst&q=clientbundle+array#ed9a23e4544a5aa8): perform the file operations on the server, and then return a list of the file (meta)data via an RPC call.

This turns out to be fairly simple, and also allows me to return lightweight references (filenames) in the list, which I use to populate a `Tree` client-side; when the user clicks on a `TreeItem` the actual text contents are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [automatic generator](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Automatically_generating_interfaces) for `CssResource` - maybe you could look at [its code](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/css/InterfaceGenerator.java) and modify it to your needs?